# Iterating through a Multidimensional Array in php without known keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am writing a web application and I believe one of the parts requires a
multidimensional array. The array holds a list of applications in a database.
I want to be able to display the list of applications by the individuals name or
a unique ID. I have this part working. Then I want to click on an individual
application and only pull up that particular row of information to fill in a form.
Currently when I do this it either brings up all of the rows from the database or
the first row only. Does anyone have any suggestions?
I am not great with explanations so I am including parts of my code. I am sorry
it's so long. I tried to reduce it as much as possible. Even though its included
in the code, i didn't include config.php because it's just my database connection.

userList.php:

```
<?php
include("config.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    <p><b><u>Users</b></u></p>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
require_once("/class/users.php");
$rowt = array(array());
$rowt = users::fillForm($rowt);
foreach($rowt as $test) {
    if(is_array($test))
    {
    echo "<a href='userDisplay.php'>".$test['name']."</a><br/>";
    }
}
?>
```

userDisplay.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <body>
        <h1>Tester</h1>
      <?php
      include("config.php");
      //declare array
      $rowt = array(array());
      //pass array into class function
      //since functions can't return more than one variable, you have to pass the
      //array and set it equal to the original variable while calling the pdo function
      $rowt = users::fillForm($rowt);
        foreach($rowt as $test=> $rowt){
      ?>
      <h2>Application for <?php echo $rowt['name']?></h2>
       <table>
         <tr><th><b>Name</b></th>
             <th><b>Phone Number</b></th>
             <th><b>Best Time to Call<b></th>
         </tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr><td><output type='text' maxlength="30" required name='name'><?php echo $rowt['name']?></output></td>
             <td><output type="text" maxlenth="30" required  name="p_num"><?php echo $rowt['phone_number']?></output></td>
             <td><output type='text' maxlength="30" required name='bc_time'><?php echo $rowt['best_call_time']?></output></td></tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr>
             <th><b>Visa Status<b></th>
             <th><b>IT Experience<b></th>
             <th><b>Relevant Experience<b></th>
         </tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr><td><output type='text' maxlength="30" required name='v_status'><?php echo $rowt['visa_status']?></output></td>
             <td><output type='text' maxlength="30" required name='it_exp'><?php echo $rowt['it_exp']?></output></td>
             <td><output type='text' maxlength="30" required name='rel_exp'><?php echo $rowt['relevant_exp']?></output></td>
         </tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr>
             <th colspan="3"><b>Description<b></th>
         </tr>
         <tr></tr>
         <tr>
             <td colspan="3"><output name="description" rows="4" cols="100"></output><?php echo $rowt['description']?>></td>
         </tr>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
echo "<a href='userList.php'>Back</a>";
?>
```

Functions from users.php users class:

```
public function insertForm() {
    $correct = false;
    try {
          $con = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
          $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          $sql = "INSERT INTO user(name, phone_number, best_call_time, description,
          visa_status, it_exp, relevant_exp) VALUES(:name, :p_num, :bc_time, :description,
          :v_status, :it_exp, :rel_exp)";

          $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->bindValue("name", $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindValue("p_num", $this->p_num, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindValue("bc_time", $this->bc_time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindValue("v_status", $this->v_status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindValue("it_exp", $this->it_exp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindValue("rel_exp", $this->rel_exp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->bindValue("description", $this->description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmt->execute();
          return "Entry Successful <br/> <a href='userForm.php'>Home</a>";
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
          return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
  public static function fillForm($rowt) {
      $successt = false;
      try{
        $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $rowt = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM&PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $rowt;
      }catch (PDOException $et) {
        echo $et->getMessage();
        return $successt;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a ?userId=... in your <a> links in userList.php, so as to tell the next script what filter it should use? -- Also, my first suggestion would be: don't mix HTML and PHP in same file!! use templating.

Comment: Templating? I've seen that advice before about the HTML and PHP but i've never heard of how to fix it. For this particular section I am calling on the individual users by name instead of user_id. There is no user_id in that particular table. For others pages in the web app with similar function I am using the date created instead of a name.

Comment: You should consider studying a templating system such as Twig or http://github.com/figdice/figdice

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a solution. I have looked at templating systems and it is a little late into the project for me to use one. If I have to redo everything or if my PM asks me to I'll go with that. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot going on here, but if I get the gist of your question you want to be able to return one individual user when a row in a list of users is clicked. To do that you would need to update your SQL query to pull a particular user. Something along the lines of:

```
// Formatting into a class to cut down on repetition.
<?php 
class User {
  private $dbConnect;

  // functionally these two are similar but I separated users and user
  // for clarity of purpose.
  public function getUsers()
  {
    // Enumerating your select columns is clearer, and more efficient.
    $sql = "SELECT name, phone_number, best_call_time, description,
      visa_status, it_exp, relevant_exp 
      FROM user";

    $result = $this->makeQuery($sql);

    return ($result) ? $result : array();
  }

  public function getUser($name)
  {
    // Enumerating your select columns is clearer, and more efficient.
    $sql = "SELECT name, phone_number, best_call_time, description,
      visa_status, it_exp, relevant_exp 
      FROM user
      WHERE name = :name";

    $param = $this->prepareUserInfo(array('name' => $name));

    $result = $this->makeQuery($sql, $param);

    return ($result) ? $result : array();
  }

  public function createUser($userInfo)
  {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(name, phone_number, best_call_time, description,
    visa_status, it_exp, relevant_exp) VALUES(:name, :p_num, :bc_time, :description,
    :v_status, :it_exp, :rel_exp)";
    $params = $this->prepareUserInfo($userInfo);

    try {
      $this->connect();

      $stmt = $this->dbConnect->prepare($sql);
      $stmt = $this->bindParams($stmt, $data);
      $stmt->execute();
      return "Entry Successful <br/> <a href='userForm.php'>Home</a>";
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      return $e->getMessage();
    }

  }

  private function prepareUserInfo($userInfo)
  {
    $infoArray = array();

    foreach ($userInfo as $key => $value) {
      // Going with your original code I'm hardcoding param type here, but 
      // you could easily write a check for data type and set param dynamically.
      $infoArray[] = array(
        'key' => $key,
        'value' => $value,
        'type' => PDO::PARAM_STR,
      );
    }
    return $infoArray;
  }

  private function makeQuery($sql, $data = array())
  {
    try{
      $this->connect();
      $stmt = $this->dbConnect->prepare($sql);

      if (!empty($data)) {
        $stmt = $this->bindParams($stmt, $data);
      }

      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM&PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      return (!empty($result)) ? $result : false;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      return false;
    }
  }

  private function bindParams($stmt, $data)
  {
    foreach ($data as $item) {
      $stmt->bindValue("name", $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindValue($item['key'], $item['value'], $item['type']);
    }
    return $stmt;
  }

  private function connect()
  {
    $dbConnect = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $dbConnect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->dbConnect = $dbConnect;
  }
}

?>
```

From there your click handler would need to trigger a `User->getUser('some name');` request. You could take this abstraction further by separating your PDO connect into it's own class and handle query building and execution from there.

Seconding the above comment about not mixing your presentation with your data layer. Check out a templating engine like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or (less advisable but sometimes necessary) roll your own by building a view loader that loads template files to an output buffer, adds dynamic variables, and returns a rendered string.

Comment: I didn't go with this solution but it helped me find my solution so thank you.